# How to convert csv file so it can be JSON serializable and vice versa?

Tags: python, django

I need to pass a csv file uploaded from a web page in celery task to call an api for each row of csv. But I get an error that `<InMemoryUploadedFile>` is not JSON serializable

I thought to convert file into json using following:

```
json.dumps(unicode(self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['uploaded_file']))
```

But it is also not working

In `views.py`:

```
class FileUploadView(FormView):
    template_name = 'addFile.html'
    form_class = FileUploadForm

    @method_decorator(sales_spear_login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FileUploadView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        file_det = self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['uploaded_file']
        create_dialer_report_async(self.request.user.email, file_det, list_name, campaign_name)
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'report_generated': True})
```

In `services.py`:

```
def create_dialer_report_async(logged_user_email, file_det, list_name, campaign_name):
create_dialer_report.apply_async((logged_user_email, file_det, list_name, campaign_name))


def create_dialer_report(user_emails, file_det, list_name, campaign_name):
reader = csv.DictReader(file_det)
for row in reader:
     # calling api from each row
```

It should be available as csv file object in services.py. However i believe this is string here.

Comment: Please format all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```py
import csv
import json

csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r')
json_file = open('your_json_file.json', 'w')

field_names = ("Your Field 1","Your Field 2","Your Field 3","Your Field 4", Your Field etc...)
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, field_names)

for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, json_file)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Hope this helps / what you were looking for.